# Tengo varios “TListView” y al selecciona uno quiero marcar los demas

Tags: delphi, delphi-tokyo

Tengo varios TListView en un Form (programó en delphi - embarcadero - X10) con el mismo “caption” y al selecciona el TListView quiero marcar las filas en los demás... puedo capturar la fila que marco, pero no se como hacer que se marque en los otros... ayuda please

Comment: Bienvenido! Este tipo de preguntas no suelen estar bien vistos en StackOverflow y por eso no recives ayuda. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Así harás mejores preguntas y podrás ser ayudado en tus problemas!!

Comment: ¿Tu proyecto es firemonkey (FMX) o VCL?. Por favor explica con mayor detalle lo que queires conseguir al decir "marcar las filas en los demás". Por ejemplo, no queda claro, si seleccionan el item `'uno'` en el `ListView1`, qué item o items son los que quieres seleccionar en el `ListView2`?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es **"sincronizar"** ambos `TListView` por el índice.
En el evento `OnSelectItem` del primero puedes saber el índice del elemento seleccionado:

```
i := ListView2.Items.Item[Item.Index];
```

Una vez que tengas el índice, debes actualizar el segundo. Para ello, buscas el elemento del segundo `TListView` con ese índice, y si lo encuentras (puede ser que no exista) lo seleccionas.

```
  i := ListView2.Items.Item[j];   // buscar el elemento por índice
  if Assigned(i) then             // si lo he encontrado...
    ListView1.Selected := i;      // lo selecciono
```

El resultado será similar a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]